# Laravel 5 - Use variables of model in model factories

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, factory, laravel-5.3

Okay, let's say that I have a Post model with the attributes `name`, `slug` and `content`. I'd like to generate models with my ModelFactory, but want to set a specific name, which I do by overwriting the value:

```
factory(App\Post::class)->create(["name" => "Something here"]);
```

But now I want the slug to auto-generate by using the (new) name and **without passing it as argument**. Like

```
"slug" => str_slug($name);
```

Is this possible or do I need to write the slug manually?
When using the factory below with `->create(['name' => 'anything']);` the slug is not created.

---

### My current factory

```
$factory->define(App\Post::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    static $name;

    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'slug' => $name ?: str_slug($name),
        'content' => $faker->sentences(),
    ];
});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should do the trick. You can pass a name in manually or let Faker handle it.

```
$factory->define(App\Post::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'slug' => function (array $post) {
            return str_slug($post['name']);
        },
        'content' => $faker->sentences(),
    ];
});
```

Comment: It works! Could you explain how you came up with the closure function and the $post array? I'll mark it as correct answer then!

Comment: If you read through the docs (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database-testing#relationships), the very last example shows how you can use closures to pass an instance of the factory. Once you have access to the correct 'name' value, you can do anything you need with it.

Comment: Ah, great idea! Haven't thought about this. Thanks a lot

Comment: this is really great, thanks for the explanation and the reference in the documentation

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
$name ="Something here";

factory(App\Post::class)->create(["name" => $name, "slug" => str_slug($name)]);
```

Comment: I don't want to pass the slug as extra argument. That wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: When I try your next solution, it gives me an error: argv is an undefined value